# How do I deal with semicolon in a cell when the file I am uploading semicolon delimited?

Tags: mysql, csv, file-upload

I am using load data infile to upload a 2gig csv file into mysql and getting some warnings that indicate that some of the cells include a semicolon when the actual csv file I am uploading is semicolon separated.

I suppose that changing the delimiter from semicolon may be an option but I do not have control over the export I am working with. Not sure how to do this without a find replace which obviously wouldnt work as it would just replace the semicolon that needs to remain in the field it has been exported to.

Here is what I am using:

```
load data infile '/file/path/bigfile.csv'  
into table table_name fields terminated by ';'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ignore 1 lines 
(Column1, Column2, Column3, ....);
```

I guess the ultimate question is can you use a regex as a delimter when using load data infile...having problems finding this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mention the fields separated by in LOAD DATA command as:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY **';'** 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

**FIELDS TERMINATED BY '**;**'** is the main part to edit in your case.

Also you might be change the delimiter from semicolon to something else..

Comment: Hmm..so in the fields terminated could I include some regex to treat semicolons as a delimiter only if it isnt followed with xyz? The semicolons I dont want treated as a delimiter all are followed by xyx.

Comment: I just pasted what I am using above.

Comment: you can change delimiter before running this query with command:  Delimiter $$

Comment: Will this avoid changing the semicolon that is not a delimiter?

Comment: Can you send me a link on how to do this? I want to know the exact way to do this. If the solution replaces all of the semicolons then my data will be corrupted. Not clear on the Delimiter $$ recommendation.

Comment: @Icm disregard the `DELIMITER $$` remarks, as they are not relevant.  That is used for declaring stored programs, when you want the *SQL statement delimiter* to be something other than `;`. The `;` here is `'` quoted so that advice isn't applicable in any way.